# Can an Android app programatically set the screen brighter than the ordinary range?

Tags: android, screen, brightness

The Android software lets you set the display brightness (0.0 - 1.0), or you can chose the auto brightness mode, which lets the device chose the brightness for you depending on the ambient lighting. The maximum brightness (1.0) gives me a bit less than 100 nits. In auto mode, my phone can go up to 850 nits.

Normally these are sensible limits. The Android software gives a guaranteed brightness on all devices. The auto brightness mode can go beyond this if your device knows how to handle it. This may include only giving peak brightness for a limited time.

I want to be able to match the brightness of a monitor on my phone. I have an app that can do this. Most monitors are brighter than the Android 100 nits limit, but less than 850 nits, so it would be good to go to peak brightness in a dark room, if only for 30 seconds.

I could make the other monitor dimmer, or put a neutral density filter on it. But it would be nicer if I could get the full brightness of the screen. But I only want to do this if it is supported for general android devices.

Comment: Honestly I'd assume the actual output of "full brightness" is controlled by the device itself, based on the ambient lighting conditions - the user doesn't get to override it, and as far as I'm aware that `0.0` to `1.0` value you can set through `WindowManager` is the only control you have in code (basically the same as the UI slider). Even if some devices do allow you to override it (including rooted ones) I wouldn't assume it's a thing you can generally do, too easy to abuse. If it's for your own use, maybe you could shine a light on your light sensor, clamp a bright LED over it or something

Comment: This is what I guess. However, 'I didn't find it' != 'it isn't there'. I can see the logic in having a baseline brightness level. However, if the device software can make the display go brighter in full sunlight without damaging it based on the light meter reading, then it could safely do the same without the light meter reading.

The other solution for me is to put an ND Roscolux filter over the monitor I am measuring.

Comment: Oh I meant protecting the user, not the device